# Combining multiple JSONs with id

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to fetch data from a public API. However, all the data I need is accessible only by calling multiple URLs.

However, each `JSON` provided have a `station_id` and I'm trying to combine the data based on this value.

I am not sure which strategy I should use to "merge" the results (see code below)

I tried calling both URL at the same time.

Also tried to add the data from the second URL after calling the first URL.

first URL (https://api-core.bixi.com/gbfs/es/station_information.json)

```
{"last_updated":1565466677,
 "ttl":10,
 "data":
      {"stations":
            [
            {"station_id":"25",
             "external_id":"0b100854-08f3-11e7-a1cb-3863bb33a4e4",
             "name":"de la Commune / Place Jacques-Cartier",
             "short_name":"6026",
             "lat":45.50761009451047,
             "lon":-73.55183601379395,
             "capacity":89,}]


// ...
```

Second URL (https://api-core.bixi.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json)

```
{"last_updated":1565466677,
 "ttl":10,
 "data":
      {"stations":
            [
            {"station_id":"25",
             "num_bikes_available": 39,
             "num_docks_available":50,}]


// ...
```

Excepted Result (This is the structure I am looking for, not the final code)

```
{"last_updated":1565466677,
 "ttl":10,
 "data":
      {"stations":
            [
            {"station_id":"25",
             "external_id":"0b100854-08f3-11e7-a1cb-3863bb33a4e4",
             "name":"de la Commune / Place Jacques-Cartier",
             "short_name":"6026",
             "lat":45.50761009451047,
             "lon":-73.55183601379395,
             "capacity":89,
             "num_bikes_available": 39,
             "num_docks_available":50}]

//...
```

Structure I tried to pass the data in

```
struct BixiApiDataModel: Codable {

    let last_updated: Int
    let ttl: Int
    let data: Stations

}

struct Stations: Codable {

    let stations: [Station]

}

struct Station: Codable {

    let station_id: String
    let num_bikes_available: Int
    let num_docks_available: Int
    let external_id: String
    let name: String
    let short_name: String
    let lat: Float
    let lon: Float
    let capacity: Int

}
```

Calling the URL

```
class Webservice {

    func loadBixiApiDataModel(url: URL, completion: @escaping ([Station]?) -> ()) {

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil)
                return
            }

            let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(BixiApiDataModel.self, from: data)

            if let response = response {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    completion(response.data.stations)
                }
            }

        }.resume()
    }

}
```

I'm trying to display the combined information of a station. I assume the data I fetch after calling the first URL isn't stored when I call the second URL.

Should I call both APIs separately, store the data and then combine everything using the `station_id` value?

Or is it possible to call each APIs and append the data from the second URL based on the `station_id`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Should I use `JSONSerialization` in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this

- Handle each download separately
- Keep the resulting data in separate structs
- Merge them into a third struct and then use that third struct internally in the app

**Handle each download separately**

Download the station information first and store it in a dictionary with `station_id` as key and then download station status and use the same id to match the downloaded elements

**Keep the resulting data in separate structs**

Since the content of the downloaded data is quite different between the to API calls I would use two different structs for them, `StationInformation` and `StationStatus`. Looking at the type of data you might actually want to download status more often than information which seems to be more static so that is another reason to keep them separate.

**Merge them into a third struct...**

I would create a third struct that contains information from the two other structs, either as just two properties (shown below) or with properties that are extracted from the others

Here is an example of how the third struct could be implemented

```
struct Station {
    let information: StationInformation
    var status: StationStatus?

    init(information: StationInformation) {
        self.information = information
    }

    var id: String {
        return information.stationId
    }

    mutating func merge(status: StationStatus) {
        guard self.id == status.stationId else { return }
        self.status = status
    }
}
```

The download function could be modified to be generic to simplify the code. First the structs need to be modified

```
struct BixiApiDataModel<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let data: Stations<T>
}

struct Stations<T: Decodable>: Decodable {
    let stations: [T]
}

struct StationInformation: Codable {
    let stationId: String
    let externalId: String
    //... rest of properties
}
struct StationStatus: Codable {
    let stationId: String
    let numBikesAvailable: Int
    let numDocksAvailable: Int
}
```

then the function signature needs to be changed to

```
func loadBixiApiDataModel<T: Decodable>(url: URL, completion: @escaping ([T]?) -> ()) {
```

and the decoding needs to be changed (notice the improved error handling, never use try?)

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
    let response = try decoder.decode(BixiApiDataModel<T>.self, from: data)
    completion(response.data.stations)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

And a simplified example of calling the function (but without any merging)

```
var informationArray: [StationInformation] = []
var statusArray: [StationStatus] = []
if let url = URL(string: "https://api-core.bixi.com/gbfs/es/station_information.json") {
    loadBixiApiDataModel(url: url, completion: {(arr: [StationInformation]?) in
        if let arr = arr { informationArray = arr }
        print(informationArray.count)
    })
} else { print("Not a valid url")}

if let url = URL(string: "https://api-core.bixi.com/gbfs/en/station_status.json") {
    loadBixiApiDataModel(url: url, completion: {(arr: [StationStatus]?) in
        if let arr = arr { statusArray = arr }
        print(statusArray.count)
    })
} else { print("Not a valid url")}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!